# Update multiple records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, webhooks

Receiving webhook info to update my contacts into my app. There is different brands -- they own their own contact.
When I received a "blocked" info from my email provider, i want the app to update all records.
For now, I know how to update only contact that belongs to its brand, but not all contact (john@doe.com can be a contact of multiples brands)

My controller :

```
def webhook
    params['_json'].each do |event|
      blocked(event) if event['event'].eql?('blocked')
    end
end
```

private

```
def blocked(event)
 campaign =  Campaign.find_by(mailjet_id: event ['mj_campaign_id'])
 return unless campaign

 contact = Contact.find_by(email: event['email'])
 return unless contact

 contact.update_attribute(:subscription, false)
end
```

I tried update_all, contact.where ect, not finding the good way to do it

Comment: What is the relationship between contacts and brands?

Comment: Contacts belong to brands

Comment: Without a mention of Brand in the code shared, it's hard to understand how this isn't already doing what you want.

Comment: Would a 'where' clause that finds all contacts with a given email help? Then you'd update all contacts with that email.

Comment: Thanks for your help.. I know, in fact at the beginning i was mentionning the brand, deleted this after. I tried with the where clause, it only update the first record (filtered by the contact id - DESC).. Also, i tried an update_all, having an error about my method...